# Unable to read checkDeviceAdminPermission

Tags: java, android

```
Button reqDeviceAdmin;

reqDeviceAdmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reqDeviceAdmin);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (!checkUsageStatsPermission(RequestPermission.this)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        if (checkDeviceAdminPermission(RequestPermission.this)){
            reqDeviceAdmin.setText(getString(R.string.uninstall_protect_is_active));
        } else {
            reqDeviceAdmin.setText(getString(R.string.uninstall_protect_is_not_active));
        }

        reqDeviceAdmin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkDeviceAdminPermission(RequestPermission.this)) {
                } else {
                    requestDeviceAdmin();
                }
            }
        });

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkDeviceAdminPermission(RequestPermission.this)) {
        reqDeviceAdmin.setText(getString(R.string.uninstall_protect_is_active));
    } else {
        reqDeviceAdmin.setText(getString(R.string.uninstall_protect_is_not_active));
    }
}
```

This code is not checking for the if(checkDeviceAdminPermission(RequestPermission.this)) condition to be true. It's always returning else condition.It's always fetching the text uninstall_protect_is_not_active. This code is in RequestPermission.java. MIN_SDK=21.

Comment: Hi Anjali, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The code is flowing through else condition but not if condition. I think checkDeviceAdminPermission(RequestPermission.this) is executing but not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am using exactly same app and i am using this type:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void checkBTPermissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

            int permissionCheck =getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }
```

If you call the checkBTpermission any where you can getting permission.